# What is a wrapper method for a delegate?

Tags: c#, methods, delegates, wrapper

I'm doing a project for school about delegates, lambdas and so forth. My professor gave me the code below and what I have to do is create anonymous methods, lambdas, delegates and funcs to put into the _DList that he made there. In his instructions, however, I came across a part that puzzled me. It says:   **Hint: Other delegates may have to be added to _DList in a wrapper-method.** 
I assume that this has to do with the fact that you can't really cast a delegate to a Func but I'm not sure.  If you could answer with a bit more insight as to what this "Hint" means, I would really appreciate it.

```
class TestDelegate
{
   private List<Func<int,double,char,string,string>> _DList;
   //other fields as needed
   public TestDelegate( )
   {
      _DList = new List<Func<int,double,char,string,string>>( );

      //other statements as needed
   }
   public void RunTests()
   {
       int idata = 1;
       double ddata = 5.1;
       char cdata = ‘A’;
       string sdata = “Method “;
       foreach(Func<int,double,char,string,string>  myDel in _DList)
          Console.WriteLine(myDel(idata,ddata++,cdata++,sdata+idata++));
   }
   //other methods, properties or indexers as needed
}//end class TestDelegate
```

Comment: `Func` *is* a delegate, so the statement "you can't really cast a delegate to a `Func`" doesn't really make sense.  The instructions you gave here are honestly rather nonsensical.  Lambdas *are* anonymous methods, and `Func`s are delegates, so putting "both" of each of those into a list doesn't really make sense.  And of course all anonymous methods compile down into a delegate, so to add all four of those things to a list means just having one item in said list.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. It doesn't really make sense but for the sake of the project,  it's what I have to do.  It's just my teacher's way of teaching about delegates I guess... Nevertheless the question remains about the wrapper-method.  I still don't know what that is supposed to mean.